# Edit Overleaf offline with comments from the online platform?

Tags: overleaf, comments, offline

I've synced with Github and have a local .tex repo that works and compiles fine. Does anyone know how I can import the comments that were made on the online Overleaf as well?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: Umm, have you contacted the Overleaf Helpdesk about this?

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) These can't be exported from Overleaf at the moment, unfortunately. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/580985/21344 for more details.